# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; change column

Tags: php, laravel

goal: change the column meta-settings in table settings.

I'm trying to change a column name in a table I created before, so I followed the steps:

1. `composer require doctrine/dbal`
2. `php artisan make:migration update_oldFileName_table`
3. `update_oldNameFile_table.php`

```
Schema::table('settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('meta-description', 'metaDescription');
});
```

4. `php artisan migrate`

However, it shows me this error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-description
> metaDescription VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE
> settings CHANGE meta-description metaDescription VARCHAR(255) NOT
> NULL)

I think the problem is because the - in "meta-description" but I want to change it!

Comment: sorry goal: change meta-description in settings table

Comment: Well, what _is_ the query executed (or, rather, rejected) by the DB? Is it as expected? Is the name even valid? Maybe implementation of the `renameColumn` method is what's faulty? Please ensure what is the case and whether this programming question shouldn't be a bug report instead! Also, always create a [mcve] and step through the code in a debugger to get an insight. As a new user here, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: BTW: You can [edit] your question and you should do that to improve it, e.g. to add a tag for the DB or to clarify your goal. Don't put important info into the comments here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add backticks around the column name:

```
$table->renameColumn('`meta-description`', 'metaDescription');
```

the problem is that - is an operator. the backticks make sure that is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You need `doctrine/dbal` package in order to perform this action.

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Run your migration again, and the error should go away.

Comment: As I wrote above, I already done that but still had that error